# How can I give dependancy to every(repeat Job ) in TWS

Tags: tivoli, tivoli-work-scheduler

How can I add dependency to Every Job for example

there are 2 job in one jobstream,both are every job mean they run at every 30 min.but I want to implement one condition in between.
Condition: 2nd job will run only after completion of 1st for every 30 min mean each instance of 2nd job will run only after each instance of 1st job
Please give me solution.I need this

Job1
every 30 min
at 10.30

Job2
every 30 min
at 10.30
follow job1

Comment: I changed the tag from tws to tivoli.  The tws tag is now for Trader Work Station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario you cannot use the every on the job, that let each job to repeat by its own and how you have seen let the 2nd job to run after the 1st job has completed the first time.

In order to have the dependency considered at each run you have to include the 2 jobs in a job stream and repeat the whole job stream

There are two possible solutions for that, depending on your scenario:

1. Use the every on job stream

   ```
   SCHEDULE JS1
    ON RUNCYCLE RC1 "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"  
     ( SCHEDTIME 1030 EVERY 0030 EVERYENDTIME 1800 )   
    ONOVERLAP ENQUEUE  
   :  
   JOB1  

   JOB2  
    FOLLOWS JOB1

   END
   ```
2. Add a 3rd job after job2 that resubmit the job stream using **conman sbs**. In this case you can use **datecalc** to calculate the AT time of the new instance.